# Test for variables with same range

Tags: python, variables, if-statement, range

is there a way to test multiple variables within the same range (x1,y1,x2,y2 in range...)?
I would like the code to be shorter after the `if`

```
mouv="7647"
x1,y1,x2,y2=int(mouv[0]),int(mouv[1]),int(mouv[2]),int(mouv[3])
if len(mouv)==4 and x1 in range(8) and y1 in range(8) and x2 in range(8) and y2 in range(8):
    print("code ok")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`all`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

```
if len(muov) == 4 and all(int(x) in range(8) for x in mouv)
```

Or if `range` is huge then it's better to use chained comparison operators as `range` creates a list in memory and is slow compared to simple mathematical comparisons:

```
if len(muov) == 4 and all(0 <= int(x) < 8 for x in mouv)
```

Comment: I have a suggestion. `if len(muov) == 4 and all(int(x) in range(8) for x in muov)`. This saves you a call to `map`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using [`all`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#all):

```
mouv = "7647"
# I cleaned this up too
x1,y1,x2,y2 = map(int, mouv[:4])
if len(mouv)==4 and all(z in range(8) for z in (x1, y1, x2, y2)):
    print("code ok")
```

---

Note that if your range is huge, you should use Python's mathematical operators instead:

```
if len(mouv)==4 and all(-1 < z < 8 for z in (x1, y1, x2, y2)):
```

With large ranges, using mathematical operators is faster than doing `x in range(n)`.  With small ranges however, the difference is negligible.